# Text incorrectly identified as code

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I was posting a question and wanted to include the contents of a plaintext file that my application parses but I received an error stating that I had improperly formatted code. Sure, it may look a bit like code but it isn't code and I thought it looked significantly nicer when used with <kbd>></kbd> rather than the four spaces for code formatting (especially since I had a block of code following this section).

---

Here are the contents of my file:

> MaxValue = 10
>   MinValue = 1

Here is my code to parse the file:

```
switch (line)
{
   case "MaxValue":
      testObject.maxValue = value;
   // etc...
}
```

---

vs

---

Here are the contents of my file:

```
MaxValue = 10
MinValue = 1
```

Here is my code to parse the file:

```
switch (line)
{
   case "MaxValue":
      testObject.maxValue = value;
   // etc...
};
```

---

I prefer the top example since it does a better job of separating the file contents from the actual code. I understand the need to properly format code but in this particular example it doesn't look as good, not to mention that it isn't code (to me).
Maybe the error box can have a button that lets the user acknowledge the message and proceed with the post?

Comment: Perhaps you should take a look at syntax-highlighting hints, and just disable the highlighter for the example file?

Comment: @Deduplicator thanks for the tip, but even after adding the line to ignore syntax highlighting it still didn't let me use '>'. All it did was show those lines as regular text.

Comment: Hmm... I edited your post and it worked just fine... I wonder if this is rep-dependent.

Comment: Interesting. I tried editing my post, undid and attempted to redo it and got the message again (attached image). Maybe you're right about it being based on rep. http://i.imgur.com/BnKMiTc.png